# Drodownbutton example using flutter bloc architecture

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies, flutter-animation, bloc

I tried with below code.

```
StreamBuilder(
    stream: _preferenseBloc.textStream,
    builder: (BuildContext context,
        AsyncSnapshot<String> snapshot) {
        return DropdownButton<String>(
        elevation: 0,
        value: snapshot.data,
        //hint: Text("Monthly"),
        items: listDrop,
        onChanged: (String newvalue) {
            dropdownValue= newvalue;
            // _preferenseBloc.dropdownValue(value);
        },
        //value: dropdownValue,
        );
    },
),
```

I am unable select the Dropdownvalue using bloc architecture in flutter.

Comment: Any one know the answer about that please post that answer.

Comment: share codes of your bloc class and entire widget please